# Displaying specific records that match a specific criteria.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a number of records that I'm looping through, and i'm trying to flag out specific records that do not match the logic within my conditional. However whatever I've been trying, my results have been all of my records.

```
User.all.map do |u|
  if [u.zip_code == true]
    u.name
  end
end
```

I feel elementary for asking this, but ultimately what i'm trying to do is flag any users that do not have a zip_code.  With what I've done, is every record is displayed regardless of if I have my conditional equaling true or false.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
User.all.map do |u|
  if u.zip_code
    u.name
  end
end
```

But what if zip_code is not true?

Comment: Sweet! This did work, and I do thank you for it. I'm curious though, why was it that the brackets that I had in the conditional limit it from working?

Comment: Because [] ? is always true.